# One-to-many relationship to multiple models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model `Thing` and a model `Action`. There is a one-to-many relationship between `Thing`s and `Action`s. However, I would like to be able to subclass `Action` to have (for example) `BuildAction`, `HealAction` and `BloodyStupidAction`. Is it possible using Flask-SQLAlchemy to do this and maintain the single one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is described in the SQLAlchemy docs under [Inheritance Configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html#inheritance-configuration).  If your different subclasses will share the same database table, you should use [single table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html#single-table-inheritance).

Code example:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    actions = db.relationship('Action', backref=db.backref('thing'))

class Action(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'action'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('thing.id'))
    discriminator = db.Column('type', db.String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}

class BuildAction(Action):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'build_action'}
    time_required = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Each subclass of `Action` should inherit the `thing` relationship defined in the parent class.  The `action.type` column describes which subclass action each row of the table represents.